# Daemon to: receive messages -> run background command -> manage number of tasks running simulatenously?

Tags: shell-script, daemon, application, fork

Looking for a unix program that runs in the background (daemon), that:

1. can receive arbitrary (JSON) messages.
2. On receiving a message, run a specified command.
3. Has option for limiting number of instances of this process that can run at a time.
4. if more messages are received than UPPERlimit add them to a queue.

Does there exist something ? Am I asking for too much ? 
I wouldn't mind a custom bash solution if that is possible.

I have looked into queueing systems like rabbitmq/beanstalk/gearman. They don't match my requirements it seems..

Ty

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, **inetd**(8).  Most Linux distributions package **xinetd**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you are looking for, but you can build simple services using `socat` to listen on a port and get it to run a shell script for example on each connection. You can limit the max simultaneous connections. Eg create a bash script `./myscript` holding:

```
#!/bin/bash
read message
echo "hello. got $message"
sleep 10
echo "bye"
```

Then launch `socat` on port 10005 with max 2 children to run the script:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:10005,reuseaddr,fork,max-children=2 SYSTEM:./myscript
```

You can now connect to this port using whatever network tool you like and interact with the script. Using bash's built-in `/dev/tcp/` feature to connect to a port, the following will suffice:

```
(echo "$(date) my message"; cat -n >&2) <>/dev/tcp/localhost/10005 >&0 &
```

If you give this command several times, only 2 will run and the rest will be queued. Typical output will be

```
1  hello. got Wed May 11 17:33:19 CEST 2016 my message
2  bye
```